# How do I get post enagement using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get post engagement for the posts on my page. However I get the following debug message in graph API explorer

```
The engagement field does not exist on the PagePost object.
```

This is what my query looks like

```
MY_PAGE/posts?fields=id,from,message,engagement,created_time,permalink_url,likes.limit(0).summary(true),insights.metric(post_engaged_users).period(lifetime)&limit=10
```

I could not find any metric on the [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/insights) page but browsing previous stackoverflow questions I found that 'engagement' is what you pass in query. I'm able to see the engagement for my posts through facebook. How can I retrieve the same using graph API?

Comment: have you found solution for this ? it's not the only metrics that the api doesn't return actually

Comment: @RamiDridi No. Could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is:

```
/{object-id}/insights?metric={metric-1},{metric-2},{metric-3},...
```

where object-id is your Page Id. You can choose the different post level metrics: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/insights#page-post-impressions

Note the different time periods for each metric.

Be sure you have the correct permissions: read_insights, pages_read_engagement

Comment: I know of the endpoint and I'm already making use of insights in my query as you can see in my question. However I can't find any metric that gives me post engagement.

Comment: By "post engagement", what metrics are you referring to? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/insights#page-post-engagement